# Encode to Base 64 with utf-8 characterset in linux

Tags: bash, encoding, character-encoding, base64

I am trying to encode the contents of a vql file to base64 with the character set utf-8.

Tried base64 file-name
but seems the encoded output is different to when i use my java code:

```java
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Documents\\pull.vql")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(text.getBytes());
System.out.println(encodedString);
```

I have tried the following too but without any luck:

```bash
base64 pull.vql -d | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5
```

Part of the Input is the following:

```
# REQUIRES-PROPERTIES-FILE - # Do not remove this comment!
# 
# Generated with Platform 8.0 update 20220815.

ENTER SINGLE USER MODE;
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


# 0 ====================================================================

# #######################################
# DATABASE
# #######################################
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE ci_cd_test 'db to implement and test ci-cd workflow';

CONNECT DATABASE ci_cd_test;

# #######################################
# FOLDERS
# #######################################
CREATE OR REPLACE FOLDER '/1 - Connectivity' ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FOLDER '/1 - connectivity/1 - data sources' ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FOLDER '/1 - connectivity/2 - base views' ;
```

Desired Output:

```
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
```

Output when using java and bash are totally different Any suggestion would be great. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an expected input and output?

Comment: Given your Java code, the encoding of the file is already UTF-8 so you can put `iconv` aside. In fact, you just need to call `base64 pull.vql`, or maybe `base64 pull.vql | tr -d '\n'` if your base64 adds unwanted newlines to the output.

Comment: i tried base64 pull.vql | tr -d '\n' : it is not giving the proper output

Comment: @Andy: Added the input and output in the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're processing the files on Linux, and wants to have a Windows output, you should first convert the Linux LE to Windows LE, e.g. by `sed`.

So `sed 's/$/\r/g' pull.vql | base64 -w 0 | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5` should get the expected result, or convert the file before conversion.

Comment: Thanks Andy : i will test this and update here

Comment: Unfortunately the quite is quite different when large vql files are used.
Im assuming its the line separators but not sure.
output of file pull.vql: pull.vql: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: Resolved the issue just removing the sed and using the following script: 
base64 -w 0 pull.vql | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5

Thanks for your suggestion Andy

Comment: @User1515 your welcome, than mark this answer like solution ;)

Comment: @Andy the `iconv` is superfluous, and even wrong; base64 strings are supposed to be pure ASCII, not anything else